# Adding a controller for ApplicationUser.cs? MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add a controller for the ApplicationUser.cs so that when a admin is logged in, they have the ability to view, edit, delete any records from the dbo.AspNetUsers table however I think I'm doing it wrong. Any ideas?

Here's the code for the ApplicationUser.cs:

```
namespace ProjectTest.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        override public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string RoleType { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        override public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        override public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I try to add a controller for the ApplicationUser model class, the controller gets created (including the view files) but fails to launch. The controller is the default code after creating a new controller.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to launch"? Can you add your controller code (the relevant bits) and exception messages?

Comment: Why not just generate a new default template project and copy the AccountController.cs from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're totally on track Dean. 
However, I'm going to walk you through how to create the controller manually, and create the edit method too. Feel free to check your generated controller for any mismatch, or better still, follow these steps entirely.

first off: I advise you create a Viewmodel (in a new file) that has only the properties you intend to expose to the admin. This View model could look like this.

```
public class UserViewModel
{    
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string RoleType { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    override public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**note that using a view model is a more standardized approach, so feel free to skip this step.**

Next: You should create a controller such as an `AdminController`like so.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
     private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dataContext;
     private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AdminController(ApplicationDbContext dataContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        // Inject the datacontext and userManager Dependencies
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    // HTTPGET Controller action to edit user
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EditUser()
    {
        return View();
    }

     // HTTPPOST Controller action to edit user
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(UserViewModel model)
    {
        //Get User by the Email passed in.
        /*It's better practice to find user by the Id, (without exposing the id to the view).
        However, to keep this example simple, we can find the user by email instead*/
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

        //edit user: replace values of UserViewModel properties 
        user.Summary = model.Summary;
        user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
        user.LastName = model.LastName;
        user.RoleType = model.RoleType;
        user.Address = model.Address;
        user.City = model.City;

         //add user to the datacontext (database) and save changes
        _dataContext.Update(user);
        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("ACTION_NAME", "CONTROLLER_NAME");
        //this could be
        //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Temi for the detailed walkthrough.

Comment: After I enter all the data in the field elements and select the save button I get the following error message: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: keyValues
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder.FindTracked(Object[] keyValues, out IReadOnlyList<IProperty> keyProperties) ProjectTest1.Controllers.UserViewModelsController+<Edit>d__7.MoveNext() in UserViewModelsController.cs
+
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);

Comment: I see. This is probably because the id wasn't passed into the EditUser controller action as an argument. I normally do not expose the user ID to the view for a lot of reasons; hence, the reason I passed in the Userviewmodel without the ID, and then the Id as a separate parameter. However, in order to make this code sample a little less cumbersome, I have made edits to the code sample, getting the user by the email instead.

Comment: Thanks Temi. I finally figured out why the userID wasn't being passed and it was because I didn't add a method to the  HTTPGet Edit

Comment: Awesome Dean. Glad you did 